# How do I tell Filebeat to use a specific NIC to send out harvested logs to Logstash?

Tags: filebeat, nic

We have three Network Interface Card (NIC) in each of our machines running RedHat Linux. I want Filebeat to use a specific NIC/IP to send out data to Logstash. I cannot find anything in Filebeat config file related to this. Would it be setup in RedHat somewhere?

Comment: It looks like there is an option to set the specific host and IP for the logstash output, but not a specific NIC. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html 

I would therefore think that this would be a RedHat setting to tell Filebeat which NIC that logstash output host and port is on. Maybe Filebeat tries to send to the host and port on all NICs, but I havent tried this scenario. But would recommend asking on the Elastic Forum for additional and maybe more targeted insights and replies and assistance https://discuss.elastic.co/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an option to set the specific host and IP for the logstash output, but not a specific NIC. [elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html](https://elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html) I would therefore think that this would be a RedHat setting to tell Filebeat which NIC that logstash output host and port is on. Maybe Filebeat tries to send to the host and port on all NICs, but I havent tried this scenario. But would recommend asking on the Elastic Forum for additional and maybe more targeted insights and replies and assistance [discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co)